# Setting my active class in my navigation with PHP

Tags: php

Hello I would like to know how to use PHP in my header so that my class active can be activated when it is on the correct page.

for instance on my index.php 
i have this at the top

```
<?php 
$page = 'Home';
include("header.php");
?>
```

then this is in my navigation

```
           <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" href="index">Home</a></li> 
                    <li class="rightside"><a href="projects">Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="rightside"><a href="about_us">About</a></li>
                    <li class="rightside"><a href="blog">Blog</a>
                    <li class="rightside"><a href="contact">Contact</a>

                </ul>
            </nav>
```

I want the class to be activated when i am on the appropriate page if that makes any sense. Thank you, my PhP knowledge is minimal.

Comment: There are many tutorials already available for this. You need to use PHP to determine what page you are on, then `if` page = this one class = whatever. There are smarter ways, however, but it depends on if you are using some template/framework system or just sticking everything inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shorthand `if` statement that can be used inline

```
<?php echo ($page == 'Home' ? 'active':'');?>
```

See Below

```
            <nav>
               <ul>
                    <li><a class="<?php echo ($page == 'Home' ? 'active':'');?>" href="index">Home</a></li> 
                    <li class="rightside"><a class="<?php echo ($page == 'Projects' ? 'active':'');?>" href="projects">Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="rightside"><a class="<?php echo ($page == 'About_us' ? 'active':'');?>" href="about_us">About</a></li>
                    <li class="rightside"><a class="<?php echo ($page == 'Blog' ? 'active':'');?>" href="blog">Blog</a>
                    <li class="rightside"><a class="<?php echo ($page == 'Contact' ? 'active':'');?>" href="contact">Contact</a>

                </ul>
            </nav>
```

I personally use a jquery function for this, it saves having to declare the page type each time

jQuery

```
$(function () {
  var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $('[href$="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always declare $page before the header include, than you can use an if statement.
Just an example:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
                <li><a class="<?php echo ($page == 'Home') ? 'active' : 'rightside'; ?>" href="index">Home</a></li> 
               <!-- same for your other list elements -->
        </ul>
</nav>
```